# ExtJs: collecting continuous responses

Tags: java, spring-mvc, extjs4

I have a mathematical problem and several algorithms that solve it. When an algorithm solves the problem, a json, which represents a plot's points, is formed. I need to show all the plots on one picture. The algorithms are processed sequentially, so I need to add a new plot to the picture as soon as the algorithm finishes processing. I've read about line plots in extjs, but I can't image how to send data (plot) sequentially.

My environment is: client side: extjs; server side: java, spring, tiles

Comment: You have to show an attempt at solving the problem, questions without code are really hard to answer accurately, it will be more like suggestions, and SO is not for code suggestions

Comment: Actually, I'm seeking for the direction to start researching. As far as I'm concerned it must be something like sockets.Continuing searching...

Comment: I've found such a discussion http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?171515-WebSocket-to-push-data-to-a-view. It seems rather close

Comment: That's my point, SO is not a forum for guiding you how to get started, it's for here's my code, it doesn't work, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those, who are interested in this theme, there are some usefull links:

1. [IBM's review article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-reverseajax1/)
2. [SPRINGSOURCE BLOG](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/05/10/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-making-a-controller-method-asynchronous/)
3. [ExtJs: Chart with Long Polling](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?66788-3.0-rc1-Chart-with-Long-Polling)

Hope, this helped somebody =)